# Android NDK Mutex

Tags: c++, android, mutex, android-ndk

I am trying to do some multithreading using the Android Native Development Kit, so I need a mutex on the C++ side.

What's the proper way to create and use a mutex with Android NDK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The NDK appears to have support for [pthread mutexes](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/xgclib/x5257.html). I've not made use of them myself.

Comment: Thanks. I came across a bunch of posts saying that this hadn't been implemented yet, but they must have been very dated. I did write a small module for NDK using pthread, and it compiled, but I never tried to run it. I was able to do the threading on the java side. Thanks anyways, I will probably end up using the module at some point.

Comment: Comment for posterity:  I have an application that is using pthread's, as well as pthread mutex's, and it is working fine, so it seems like they are implemented, and work.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how we go on Windows and Android (OS_LINUX define is for Android):

```
class clMutex
{
public:
    clMutex()
    {
#ifdef OS_LINUX
        pthread_mutex_init( &TheMutex, NULL );
#endif
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
        InitializeCriticalSection( &TheCS );
#endif
    }

    /// Enter the critical section -- other threads are locked out
    void Lock() const
    {
#ifdef OS_LINUX
        pthread_mutex_lock( &TheMutex );
#endif
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS

        if ( !TryEnterCriticalSection( &TheCS ) ) EnterCriticalSection( &TheCS );
#endif
    }

    /// Leave the critical section
    void Unlock() const
    {
#ifdef OS_LINUX
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &TheMutex );
#endif
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
        LeaveCriticalSection( &TheCS );
#endif
    }

    ~clMutex()
    {
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
        DeleteCriticalSection( &TheCS );
#endif
#ifdef OS_LINUX
        pthread_mutex_destroy( &TheMutex );
#endif
    }

#ifdef OS_LINUX
    // POSIX threads
    mutable pthread_mutex_t TheMutex;
#endif
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    mutable CRITICAL_SECTION TheCS;
#endif
};
```

As one of the developers of [Linderdaum Engine](http://www.linderdaum.com) i recommend checking out for Mutex.h in our SDK.

Answer (score 9):

It's been a while since this questions was answered, but I would like to point out that the Android NDK now supports `C++11` and beyond, so it is now possible to use `std::thread` and  `std::mutex` instead of `pthreads`, here's an example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int count = 0;
std::mutex myMutex;

void increment_count() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);

    // Safely increment count
    count++

    // std::mutex gets unlocked when it goes out of scope
}

void JNICALL package_name_class_runMutexExample() {
    // Start 2 threads
    std::thread myThread1(increment_count);
    std::thread myThread2(increment_count);

    // Join your threads
    myThread1.join();
    myThread2.join();
}
```

Comment: This is now the best, most cross-platform answer, and should be higher.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <pthread.h>

class CThreadLock  
{
public:
    CThreadLock();
    virtual ~CThreadLock();

    void Lock();
    void Unlock();
private:
    pthread_mutex_t mutexlock;
};

CThreadLock::CThreadLock()
{
    // init lock here
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexlock, 0);
}

CThreadLock::~CThreadLock()
{
    // deinit lock here
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexlock);
}
void CThreadLock::Lock()
{
    // lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexlock);
}
void CThreadLock::Unlock()
{
    // unlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexlock);
}
```