# Show value in progressbar from native method 

Tags: java-native-interface, progress-bar, android-ndk

I have some native code and want to update the progressbar from the native code. There isn't no return value because it is a long duration task.
I found a small example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html but when I move the update part in a extra method I get a NullPointerException.
It seems that this part must be in the thread of the progressbar.

I tried another way by using the `AsyncTask` as nested class, but I haven't access on the method `publishProgress` from anywhere outside the class itself.

Is there any possibility to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to break your long task into multiple incremental calls then I'd recommend doing that. Then you can make those calls from a loop inside AsyncTask.doInBackground(), just like in the SDK examples.

If that's not possible, you'll need a progress variable in your native code that can safely be accessed from multiple threads: Write to it from your worker code and read it from a new "getProgress()" JNI function, with the [appropriate synchronisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144496/android-ndk-mutex) done in native code. You would then be able to call your getProgress() function from AsyncTask.doInBackground(), or whatever UI scheme you choose to use.

Comment: When the task is running the method doInBackground is blocked, isn't it?

Comment: In the first scenario, yes. In the second scenario, you'd only lock your mutex in the worker thread when updating the progress, and unlock it when doing the actual work, so that getProgress() doesn't block much. You'd probably want to sleep() between getProgress() calls.

Comment: Oh is misunderstand you. I give it a try.

Comment: Ah, I think I can see the confusion -- In the second scheme, you'd need yet another thread for the worker thread (separate to your async task thread). You might prefer to just poll getProgress() from your UI thread.

Comment: Yes I started in Java a Thread with the worker and after that the AsyncTask. Now I try to get both together. My worker throws exceptions and it would be nice, when the progressdialog would react.