# How to postpone nativeactivity call untill java objects are initialized?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-activity

I am attempting to initialize some variables in java and then send them to my native code. I need to delay the nativeactivity call so that the java variables get time to get initialized and then they can be passed to the native activity.

My main problem is that the native activity keeps being called as soon as my activity starts as i have extended my class from NativeActivity(which is compulsory). As soon as onCreate() is called after super my native activity automatically is started and my java variables are not initialized yet.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with boost. What is it?

Comment: In short way, it is an open source cross platform C++ library. I had a similar situation as you have and I solved it using mutexes and condition variables from Boost. It might complicate things more than it is necessary in your case so I won't go into details.

Comment: But basic approach is to have some kind of a mechanism that, Java should notify C++ that initialization is complete (JNI sets a bool in C++, call it bool initComplete; JNI function just sets initComplete = true;) and C++ side should wait until Java notification is sent. Simple loop might hang the system but I am not sure.

Comment: eozgonul- I tried using a loop with a flag variable that i was sending from java. As u guessed, the application hangs.

Comment: Using condition variables and mutexes is not hard on Boost but getting it to work with Android gets compelling at times. I don't know much about native mutexes but this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144496/android-ndk-mutex

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler into your class.

Below is my code which is working to perform delay operations:

```
private void cal(){     
 final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      int i=0;
      public void run()
      {                                     
       if(i==0)
        {      
          // Enter your code here which you want run after some deley.                   

    i++;
        }
        handler2.postDelayed(this, 2000);
      }
     };   
   handler2.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); 
    }
```

Call this function into your main class.

Hope it will work for you also.

Thanks

Comment: How can you control native call through handler, as soon as on onCreate() call it looks for super.onCreate(), as soon as it find super.onCreate() it start executing native code, where should he put handler, have you ever work in jni or native code ??

Comment: I need a way to delay the nativeactivity call not the entire activity. I need the activity to run so that the other variables are initialized before i can send them as parameters to the nativeactivity.